# Identify user with a specific information

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

How to identify an user with specific information like unique id or reference number in ejabberd API for chat?

I want to chat with someone then user has some information except name which is unique for that specific user. so we can identify the user in chat based on that?

on register user while calling /api/register API, there is no any unique response which is useful to make chat with another user

Even, /api/registered_users given only name of all the registered users, not any unique information

So, what is the solution?
any other APIs is there for the same or what?

Answer (score 0):

A user (that may be a person, or a machine, or an animal) can register an account in ejabberd (or any other server). That account is identified by the account username and host, for example tom@example.com.

The user uses an account, and the account is identified by the account username and host.

There is nothing else. What else could there be?

Comment: Hello, 

Actually, I'm asking about kind of primary/unique key related thing like any database table have for all rows/records

So, is there any information in backend which is related to primary/unique key for that particular user ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.